# how do I upload files to my google app engine project without deploying?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, server

I need to upload files to my Google app engine java server 
and I don`t want to deploy the whole project each time i add or update a file.
how can that be done?

for example i have images i want to add and change the logging.properties level

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As updating the code or part of it will be always needed (even if you only wanat upload statics files), there is no way to upload specific files, what you can do is to set up a Git repositorie to enable the Push-to-Deploy feature [1].

If you'd die for having this functionality, you could give it a try opening a feature request [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy-quickstart

[2] https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Layo. I actually have the server also on github repository. If I sync it with google app engine I`d be able to push specific files without deploying the project?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, most likely it'll update/deploy the whole project but on your side you have uploaded only the new/modified files (regular git push). I though you corcerns were more about your side of the updating process. What do you really want to accomplish by forcing App Engine to internally just update specific files?

Comment: I see. Maybe I`m missing something. What I need to accomplish is very simple. My Google app engine server sends pics to my android client. I need to add pics to the project regularly and wouldn't want to deploy the entire project each time I need to add a pic.

Comment: You may want to use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview) to store/serve your pics (in fact, is ment to be CDN).

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is the way to go using Google app engine and from what i could see the only way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ./appcfg.sh update command it will upload only the modified files

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Uploading_the_App

```html
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: '/var/folders/cy/rj8846m10y7cf9fvlqsd02q40000gn/T/appcfg8132912209396336329.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
28% Cloning 52 static files.
31% Cloning 64 application files.
40% Uploading 2 files.
52% Uploaded 1 files.
61% Uploaded 2 files.
68% Initializing precompilation...
73% Sending batch containing 1 file(s) totaling 9KB.
77% Sending batch containing 1 blob(s) totaling 9KB.
90% Deploying new version.
95% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
98% Uploading index definitions.

Update for module default completed successfully.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Albertoiml. Do you mean it will upload the files without deploying the entire project? I tried using the appcfg.sh update command but it returned an error -"this file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action..." when i ran appcfg update(with out the .sh) it worked but updated the entire project files.

Comment: What i did was the following:
cd /pathtosdks/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.15/bin
./appcfg.sh --oauth2 update /pathtoproject/war
As far as I know, it only upload the modified files.

Comment: `appcfg` only uploads new or modified files.

Comment: I see thank you. I`ll test to see if it only uploads the files and not deploy the project

Comment: I tried using update as you suggested but it deployed the entire project and not only copied the new/updated files.